# forEach for Uint8ClampedArray

Tags: javascript, arrays

The getImageData function returns a special array object called [`Uint8ClampedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray) which inherits many of the familiar array methods.  [`ForEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/forEach) points you to the generic method.

Let's try one:

```
var g = new Uint8ClampedArray([1,2,3,4,5]);
undefined

g
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

g.forEach(function(x){ return x + 1; } )
undefined

g
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Nothing happened.  The answer should be `[2,3,4,5,6]` what is wrong here?

---

This was done in Chrome's JavaScript terminal -- in the developer tools.

Also I found this helpful:

> The `Uint8ClampedArray` typed array represents an array of 8-bit unsigned integers clamped to 0-255; if you specified a value that is out of the range of [0,255], 0 or 255 will be set instead. The contents are initialized to 0. Once established, you can reference elements in the array using the object's methods, or using standard array index syntax (that is, using bracket notation).

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return anything. I think you're looking for `map` if you want to do some kind of 1-1 transform. In the docs you linked you can see it returns `undefined` for `forEach`.

Comment: forEach uses call by value and not call by reference, so the initial value of x inside the array can't be changed using forEach. You can simply use for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forEach` doesn't return any value, it's basically just a for loop over the contents. If you want to do a 1-1 transform and return a new array, then use the `map` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).